# TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined - @ng-toolkit/universal

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to implement ssr with angular universal and came across this npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-toolkit/universal), which does pretty much all the work for you. I used ng add command to integrate this package with my project. There were some errors I had to fix on my own. Once everything is cleared I ran npm run build:prod and got this error.

~/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs.js:89
                describe: optionsSchema.definitions.output.properties.path.description,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

how can I get this cleared

Answer (score 2):

Solution: upgrade webpack-cli to 3.1.1 in package.json and run npm i.

[reference](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8082#issuecomment-424314462)